# Why emmet.vim don't expand CSS abbreviation?

Tags: plugin-emmet-vim, filetype-scss

To input `w100p` and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>   or  `w100p` and <kbd>tab</kbd>,`w100p` can't expand into `width: 100%`.
No `snippets.json` file found  with command `find /  -name  'snippets.json'`,is it the reason?
snippets.json can download from url.
[snippets.json](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/snippets.json)

Where to put snippets.json in my vim installed directory?

```
tree  -L 1  /usr/share/vim/vim74
/usr/share/vim/vim74
├── autoload
├── bugreport.vim
├── bundle
├── colors
├── compiler
├── debian.vim
├── delmenu.vim
├── doc
├── evim.vim
├── filetype.vim
├── ftoff.vim
├── ftplugin
├── ftplugin.vim
├── ftplugof.vim
├── gvimrc_example.vim
├── indent
├── indent.vim
├── indoff.vim
├── keymap
├── lang
├── macros
├── menu.vim
├── mswin.vim
├── optwin.vim
├── plugin
├── print
├── rgb.txt
├── scripts.vim
├── spell
├── synmenu.vim
├── syntax
├── tutor
└── vimrc_example.vim
```

In the mannual ,
Create snippets.json file in extensions folder to add or override snippets.

Comment: Read `emmet-vim` README - https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim#adding-custom-snippets

Comment: This seems trivially answered by reading the official readme for emmet-vim (something which should have been part of the basic research before asking this question), and grodzik even linked to the specific part. Given that you've opened a bounty several days after grodzik's comment, you seem to think that the readme is insufficient. Could you [edit] your question to explain why it's insufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
```

copy https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/snippets.json into ~./vim/snippets.json

```
vim .vimrc
let g:user_emmet_settings = webapi#json#decode(join(readfile(expand('~/.vim/snippets.json')), "\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

i've just stuck into the same problem while trying to add emmet abbreviations in vue.js single-file components, inside style section with stylus lang enabled.

So i checked out this docs:

```
:help emmet-css-expression-syntax
```

and found out, that we should use `|` symbol after abbreviation for our cursor position, and there are plenty other tricks. Just check it out.

[image]